# How to translate web pages to epub?

Tags: epub, conversion, html

I have a Kobo H2O Aura ebook reader. It uses the getpocket application: I send the link of a web article from my registered e-mail address to a central getpocket address, and when I turn on my ebook reader it downloads the article in ebook format so I can read long articles at ease.

But this does not work all the time: some articles simply do not go through, and some have flaws, like missing important blocks from the original articles.

Is there a good software or programming environment that helps creating a simplistic epub from a web page?

The Chrome WebToEpub extension does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the superb, free, [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) utility [to convert HTML to EPUB](https://www.epubor.com/how-to-convert-html-to-epub.html). That said, there are limitations to any format conversion. For example, HTML is designed as a markup language, and EPUB is not as facile with links.

BTW, since Calibre is available for most operating systems, you can use that as a reader (although I find the multi-platform [Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) a better general-purpose viewer).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a website to ePUB using https://webpagetoepub.github.io/ .